# Maintaining Parenmt child relationship using array

Tags: php, wordpress

How do I rearrange the following array

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1
        [1] =>  Electronic
        [2] =>  0
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 2
        [1] =>  mobile
        [2] =>      1
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => 3
        [1] =>  Tv
        [2] =>      1
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => 4
        [1] =>  smartphone
        [2] =>  2
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [0] => 5
        [1] =>  freeze
        [2] =>      1
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [0] => 6
        [1] =>  lg
        [2] =>      5
    )

[6] => Array
    (
        [0] => 7
        [1] =>  philips
        [2] =>  3
    )

[7] => Array
    (
        [0] => 8
        [1] =>  Onida
        [2] =>      3
    )

[8] => Array
    (
        [0] => 9
        [1] =>  Samsung
        [2] =>  3
    )

[9] => Array
    (
        [0] => 10
        [1] =>  Apple
        [2] =>      4
    )

[10] => Array
    (
        [0] => 11
        [1] =>  Apple 1.0
        [2] =>  10
    )

[11] => Array
    (
        [0] => 12
        [1] =>  Sasmung flat
        [2] =>  9
    )
```

to create a parent child relationship  having Parent with their respective child and save them in database. I want to save them as Wordpress categories and Show the result in wp-admin categories as categories are shown. looking forward for help.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just [register a new taxonomy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy)? Make sure hierarchical is set to true.